# R - subset data frame - check if value lies in range

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have the following two data frames

```
d1 <- data.frame(chr = c("chr1","chr2","chr2"), pos = c(11, 15,21), type = c("type1","type2","type1"))

    > d1
    chr pos  type
 1 chr1  11 type1
 2 chr2  15 type2
 3 chr2  21 type1


d2 <- data.frame(chr = c("chr1","chr2","chr4"), start = c(10, 15,30), stop = c(13,20,40))

   > d2
   chr start stop
1 chr1    10   13
2 chr2    15   20
3 chr4    30   40
```

I want to subset d1 on two conditions:

- keep all lines where 'type' == "type1" (I know how to do this)
- keep all lines where 'chr' matches any of the lines in d2 and 'pos' falls between the 'start' and 'stop' values from that line in d2

The resulting d3 would in this case then only contain line 1 of d1:

```
    > d3
    chr pos  type
 1 chr1  11 type1
```

I would start like this:

```
 d3 <- subset(d1, d1$type == "type1" & ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can add all the conditions together into one logical condition to subset

```
d1[d1$type=="type1" & d1$chr %in% d2$chr & d1$pos >= d2$start & d1$pos <= d2$stop, ]

#   chr pos  type
#1 chr1  11 type1
```