# R or pandas. If value of column in df A within range given by 2 columns in df B, print row in A

Tags: r, pandas, dataframe

Using python pandas or R:

I have a data frame A, with millions of rows:

```
CHR SNP POS
1 rs2073813 753541
1 rs3131969 754182
2 rs3131968 754192
2 rs3131967 754334
3 rs3115859 754503
3 rs3131966 900000
```

and another data frame B (also millions of rows):

```
CHR start end 
1 700500 833300
2 1000 20000
2 59998 60000 
3 700000 800000
```

For each "POS" in A, I want to check whether it is present within a range given by "start" and "end" of B (check each line in B). Also, CHR in A should also match CHR of B. If these conditions are met, print the row in A. Lines in A are unique and sorted according to POS in A. Each line in B is also unique.

For instance, POS 753541 from A is within the range 700500 to 833300, and CHR=1 from A and CHR=1 B also match, so print:

```
1 rs2073813 753541
```

At the end I want to obtain a data frame C like this:

```
CHR SNP POS
1 rs2073813 753541
1 rs3131969 754182
3 rs3115859 754503
```

Comment: I believe this to have already been answered using R. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57266240/r-subset-data-frame-check-if-value-lies-in-range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [his edit, cddt has suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58142547/3817004) to use a *non-equi join*.

Unfortunately, *non-equi joins* are somewhat tricky. In order to produce the expected result we need to tell to pick `POS` from the first data.table `A`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(A) # coerce to data.table
setDT(B) 
A[B, on = .(CHR, POS >= start, POS <= end), .(CHR, SNP, x.POS), nomatch = 0]
```

> ```
>    CHR       SNP    POS
> 1:   1 rs2073813 753541
> 2:   1 rs3131969 754182
> 3:   3 rs3115859 754503
> ```

This is achieved by the prefix `x.`

**Alternatively**, (and perhaps somewhat more intuitive) we can return the row indices of the matching rows by

```
A[B, on = .(CHR, POS >= start, POS <= end), nomatch = 0, which = TRUE]
```

> ```
> [1] 1 2 5
> ```

and subset `A` accordingly:

```
A[A[B, on = .(CHR, POS >= start, POS <= end), nomatch = 0, which = TRUE]]
```

> ```
>    CHR       SNP    POS
> 1:   1 rs2073813 753541
> 2:   1 rs3131969 754182
> 3:   3 rs3115859 754503
> ```

#### `foverlaps()`

This is a less elegant alternative:

```
foverlaps(A[, POS2 := POS], setkey(B), by.x = c("CHR", "POS", "POS2"), nomatch = 0)
```

> ```
>    CHR  start    end       SNP    POS   POS2
> 1:   1 700500 833300 rs2073813 753541 753541
> 2:   1 700500 833300 rs3131969 754182 754182
> 3:   3 700000 800000 rs3115859 754503 754503
> ```

#### Data

```
library(data.table)

A <- fread("CHR SNP POS
1 rs2073813 753541
1 rs3131969 754182
2 rs3131968 754192
2 rs3131967 754334
3 rs3115859 754503
3 rs3131966 900000")

B <- fread("CHR start end 
1 700500 833300
2 1000 20000
2 59998 60000 
3 700000 800000")
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer, but I have to ask, is to really necessary to use `x.` to specify that it takes `POS` from `A`, since `POS` only exists in `A`? And if we have to specify `POS`, why not `SNP` too?

Comment: Thanks very much both of you !!

Answer (score 1):

Using `data.table`, set up the sample data:

```
library(data.table)
A <- data.table(CHR = c(1,1,2,2,3,3), SNP = c('rs2073813', 'rs3131969', 'rs3131968', 'rs3131967', 'rs3115859', 'rs3131966'), POS = c(753541,754182,754192,754334,754503,900000))
B <- data.table(CHR = c(1,2,2,3), start = c(700500, 1000, 59998, 700000), end = c(833300, 20000, 60000, 800000))
```

Then merge `A` and `B` on `CHR`:

```
merged_all <- merge(x = A, y = B, on = 'CHR')
```

Then filter the merged data to only include the rows and columns which fulfill your criteria:

```
out <- merged_all[(POS > start & end > POS), .(CHR, SNP, POS)]
> out
   CHR       SNP    POS
1:   1 rs2073813 753541
2:   1 rs3131969 754182
3:   3 rs3115859 754503
```

**Edit:**

Updating with a much more efficient option:

```
out <- A[B, on = .(CHR, POS >= start, POS <= end), .(CHR, SNP, POS), nomatch = 0]
> out
   CHR       SNP    POS
1:   1 rs2073813 700500
2:   1 rs3131969 700500
3:   3 rs3115859 700000
```

This joins the tables directly.

NB: it's not clear whether you require inclusive or exclusive ranges (`>` or `>=`). You can adjust accordingly.

Comment: while this is a valid solution in general, merging on `CHR` is likely blow up the data and overflow the memory (we are merging millions and millions here).

Comment: @QuangHoang I have edited my post with an option which should be better from a memory perspective.